# How to copy char array to a double pointer in C

Tags: c, arrays

Im writing a fairly simple program to read a file line by line and store it into an array of lines, my program compiles fine but it crashes everytime I run it. 
This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <string.h>
#define LINESIZE 512

typedef struct { 
char **data; 
size_t nused; 
} lines_t;  

lines_t readlines(FILE *fp); 

int main(int argc,char* argv[]) { 
    FILE *fp; 
   (void)argc; 
   if((fp = fopen(argv[1],"r+")) == 0) { 
      perror("fopen"); 
   }
   readlines(fp); 
   return 0; 
}

lines_t readlines(FILE *fp) {
    lines_t line_data;
    char line[LINESIZE]; 
    char temp[20];  
    int num_lines = 0; 
    (*line_data.data) = (char *)malloc(LINESIZE); 
    while(fgets(line,LINESIZE,fp)) { 
        sscanf(line,"%s\n",temp); 
        strcpy(line_data.data[num_lines], temp); /* Program crashes here */
        num_lines++;  
    } 
    return line_data; 
}
```

The line where I try to copy my array is giving me trouble, So my question is, How do I copy my character array `temp` into the `char **data` inside `struct lines_t` if I am not doing it right?

Comment: Where is char **data is being allocated memory? you need to malloc it first inside readlines

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are dereferencing an invalid pointer here:

```
(*line_data.data) = (char *)malloc(15);
```

`line_data.data` is a `char **`. You are trying to deference it but it is not yet set to any meaningful value. You need to allocate memory for `line_data.data` before you allocate memory for `*line_data.data`.

`(char *)malloc(15)` is particularly suspicious also. Where does `15` come from and what are you actually allocating memory for? Casting the result of `malloc` is generally considered bad practice, and in your case, rightly so, because `malloc` is declared in `stdlib.h` and you aren't including that header. If you want to allocate enough space to hold 15 `char *`, then use `malloc(15 * sizeof(char *))` or alternatively, `malloc(15 * sizeof(*line_data.data))` (here it is safe to use `*line_data.data` even if it doesn't point to anything, because `sizeof` does not evaluate its operand).

Comment: Thanks! allocating for both `line_data.data` and `*line_data.data` worked, yes I forgot to add the `<stdlib.h>` for malloc when I edited it

Answer (score 0):

You can try `malloc line_data.data` before `strcpy`.

```
lines_t readlines(FILE *fp) {
    lines_t line_data;
    line_data.data = malloc(LINESIZE);
    *line_data.data = malloc(LINESIZE);

    return line_data; 
}
```

Comment: `LINESIZE` is surely not the right size to use in the first malloc

Answer (score 0):

You first need to allocate memory.
You need to allocate both for the array of strings and string array. Here you need to have an upper limit while calling a malloc.

```
line_data = malloc(10* sizeof(char*));  // for example here the upper limit is 10
while(fgets(line,LINESIZE,fp)) { 
        sscanf(line,"%s\n",temp); 
        line_data.data[num_lines] = malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(temp)+1));
        strcpy(line_data.data[num_lines], temp); /* Program crashes here */
        num_lines++;  
    }
```

Comment: You forgot about strings having null terminators